# Как импортировать template django из одного приложения в другое?

Tags: django

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container single posts-single">

 <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
 <ul>
   <li>Автор: {{ post.author }}</li>
   <li>Последнее редактирование: {{ post.post_modified }}</li>
   <li>Дата создания: {{ post.post_date }}</li>
   <li><a href="{% url 'single' id=post.id slug=post.slug %}/edit/">Редактировать</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div>{{ post.content|safe }}</div>    

{% block comments %}

{% endblock comments %}

</div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

В блок comments нужно вывести темплейт из приложения comments в приложение blog. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?